# Generate CREATE TABLE scripts using Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssms

I'm looking for a way to generate the scripts for my tables.

Comment: You want to see a list of tables, or you want to see a list of queries that are running against these tables?

Comment: i want to view created tables' queries.

Comment: I don't know what that means, sorry. What is a "created table query"?

Comment: i created tables with designer, but now i need that table creating queries but i dont wanna write 'em again. ok?

Comment: I think he wants something akin to the phpmyadmin feature that says "show php code" or "create php code". Memory fuzzy on the actual name.

@AhmetTezcan mr.tezcan I believe you are currently trying to do some kind of homework but to answer some of your questions before they happen please read some tutorials such as [link](http://w3schools.com)[/link] so that you get some fundamental familiarity with the technologies. you will have a better understanding of the answers given to you and you will be able to ask better questions that are more precise and useful.

Comment: This is a valid programming question; it should not have been closed.  Scripts generated in this way can be called by or used within code.

Answer (score 34):

Right-click the table in Object Explorer, and choose Script Table As > Create To > New Query Editor Window.

[image]

You can also do this for multiple tables by using Object Explorer Details (F7):

[image]

Or right-click the database and use the Tasks > Generate Scripts wizard:

[image]

Comment: i dont mean list of tables, i want to view created tables' queries

Comment: or i should ask it like this: "How can i backup my tables on my windows hosting, i tried backuping but i dont have permissions. So, i need these tables' queries"

Comment: you can not back up the database in a practical way without the necessary privileges. are you just trying to back up the table structure without the values?

Comment: Great example. Just wanted to mention that it does not work on linked servers. You need to be physically logged in to the instance you are trying to query.

Comment: Is it possible to trigger this "generate script" programmatically, for example from ADO.NET?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Probably using SMO, but it's not the kind of code I write...

Comment: @TimSchmelter P.S. [I asked for a T-SQL way to do this several years ago (closed as "Won't Fix")](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/273934). [This answer from Gordon](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11853825/61305) demonstrates how complex this can get, and [this question over on dba.se](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/53085/is-there-a-way-to-generate-table-create-script-in-tsql) might be useful as well.

Comment: Was just doing this for a bunch of tables, and it doesn't do the creation of indexes when using object explorer details. Only the generate scripts wizard will do this when you click the advanced button.

Comment: @bpfrenchak Object Explorer and Object Explorer Details should both obey your preferences under Tools > Options > SQL Server Object Explorer > Scripting > Table and View Options > Script Indexes. If you are not getting indexes then this must be set to false.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Yep that did it, you rock!