# Generate **bare** CREATE TABLE and CREATE PROC statemnts in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2008

The deployment procedures in my company require that SQL scripts for creation of procedures and tables, etc. be bare.

Generating create scripts in SQL Server Management Studio gives you significantly more than a bare script, which is unfortunate in this case.  For example, for a test table this is what SSMS generated for me:

```
USE [DemoDB]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[example]    Script Date: 08/07/2012 15:46:32 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[example](
    [fake_row] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

**So, what I'd like to know is:**

Can I somehow run a query on SQL Server in SSMS that would give me a script that was literally just the following?

```
create table example (
    fake_row int
)
```

Comment: So if a table is created with a primary key, or a not null constraint, or using a partitioning function, or in a schema other than dbo, you don't want any of those in the resulting script? You just want table name with no schema, data type with no other constraints, no filegroup information, nothing? Do you not think that can cause problems down the road, depending on the purpose of these scripts?

Comment: How do you end up with such a requirement, and not an equal requirement to maintain original scripts, rather than generating scripts from the current DB?

Comment: Can't you just delete the extraneous information?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Their deployment procedures script the constraints, indices, triggers, etc. separately and they have a large system for this.  In any case, this is what I need :) It's a very large company, I'm sure they have their reasons for this whatever they be.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I can, but there are many, many databases and they have a very large number of tables.  I'm sure I'll have to do this more than once, so it would be nice if there is a way to get SQL Server to do it without having to write some extra utility.  Thanks though :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apologies for the self-answer, marking other good answers +1.

**It turns out you can get pretty much all of the way there with  utility in SSMS.**

1. Right click on the database in the object explorer
2. Click "Tasks"
3. Click "Generate Scripts"
4. Select "Script Specific Objects" and choose tables, or whatever else
5. Select "Save To File" & "Single File Per Object" (or just spool to query window)
6. Click "Advanced" and you can enable/disable the generation of virtually every part of the statements you're generating including constraints, use statements, etc.
7. If further removal is required (e.g. removing GO), it's minimal

Answer (score 4):

You can create your own "create table" statements, using information_schema (Aaron . . . I know, INFORMATION_SCHEMA ;).

I have written some code for this purpose, but it doesn't use INFORMATION_SCHEMA.  I know, if uses older system tables that are probably scheduled to be removed.  It also adds in some additional information (which you can remove, since you don't need it).  Just put the list of tables in the @INCLUSIONLIST and run this in the database where the tables reside.

```
SET @INCLUSIONLIST = '|table1|table2|';

SELECT (CASE WHEN rownum = 1 THEN 'CREATE TABLE ['+a.t_name+'] ('
             WHEN c.column_id IS NOT NULL
             THEN '    ['+c.c_name+'] ' +
                  (CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('CHAR', datatype) > 0 THEN datatype+'('+(case when length < 0 then 'max' else cast(length as varchar) end)+')'
                        WHEN CHARINDEX('BINARY', datatype) > 0 THEN datatype+'('+cast(length as varchar)+')'
                        WHEN datatype = 'float' AND precision <> 24 THEN datatype+'('+cast(precision as varchar)+')'
                        WHEN datatype IN ('numeric', 'decimal') AND scale = 0 THEN datatype+'('+cast(precision as varchar)+')'
                        WHEN datatype IN ('numeric', 'decimal') AND scale > 0 THEN datatype+'('+cast(precision as varchar)+','+cast(scale as varchar)+')'
                        ELSE datatype END)+' '+
                  (CASE WHEN c.identity_seed IS NOT NULL
                        THEN 'IDENTITY(' + CAST(identity_seed AS VARCHAR) + ',' + CAST(identity_increment AS VARCHAR) + ') '
                        ELSE '' END) +
                  (CASE WHEN c.is_nullable = 0 THEN 'NOT NULL ' ELSE '' END) +
                  (CASE WHEN c.default_definition IS NOT NULL
                        THEN 'DEFAULT '+default_definition ELSE '' END) +
                  (CASE WHEN max_column_id = column_id AND pk.pk_name IS NULL THEN '' ELSE ',' END)
            WHEN rownum = max_column_id + 2 and pk.pk_name IS NOT NULL
            THEN '    PRIMARY KEY ('+pk.pk_columns+')'
            WHEN rownum = max_column_id + 3 THEN ')  /* CREATE TABLE '+a.t_name+' */'
            WHEN rownum = max_column_id + 4 THEN 'GO'
            WHEN rownum = max_column_id + 5 THEN ''
        END)
 FROM (SELECT t.t_name, rownum, max_column_id
       FROM (SELECT t.name as t_name, MAX(c.column_id) as max_column_id
             FROM sys.columns c join
                  (SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE CHARINDEX('|'+name+'|', @INCLUSIONLIST) > 0 ) t 
                  ON c.object_id = t.object_id
             GROUP BY t.name) t join
            (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY object_id) as rownum FROM sys.columns c) ctr
            ON ctr.rownum <= t.max_column_id + 5
      ) a LEFT OUTER JOIN
      (SELECT t.name as t_name, c.column_id, c.name AS c_name, u.name as datatype,
              ISNULL(baset.name, N'') AS systemtype,
              CAST(CASE WHEN baset.name IN (N'nchar', N'nvarchar') AND c.max_length <> -1
                        THEN c.max_length/2 ELSE c.max_length END AS INT) AS length,
              c.precision AS precision,
              c.scale as scale,
              c.is_nullable,
              dc.definition as default_definition,
              idc.seed_value as identity_seed, idc.increment_value as identity_increment
       FROM sys.tables t JOIN
            sys.all_columns AS c
            ON c.object_id = t.object_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
            sys.types u
            ON u.user_type_id = c.user_type_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
            sys.types baset
            ON baset.user_type_id = c.system_type_id AND 
               baset.user_type_id = baset.system_type_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
            sys.default_constraints dc
            ON c.object_id = dc.parent_object_id AND
               c.column_id = dc.parent_column_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
            sys.identity_columns idc
            ON c.object_id = idc.object_id AND
               c.column_id = idc.column_id
      ) c
      ON a.t_name = c.t_name AND
         c.column_id + 1 = a.rownum LEFT OUTER JOIN
      (SELECT t.name as t_name, kc.name as pk_name, 
              (MAX(CASE WHEN index_column_id = 1 THEN '['+c.name+']' ELSE '' END) +
               MAX(CASE WHEN index_column_id = 2 THEN ','+'['+c.name+']' ELSE '' END) +
               MAX(CASE WHEN index_column_id = 3 THEN ','+'['+c.name+']' ELSE '' END) +
               MAX(CASE WHEN index_column_id = 4 THEN ','+'['+c.name+']' ELSE '' END) +
               MAX(CASE WHEN index_column_id = 5 THEN ','+'['+c.name+']' ELSE '' END) +
               MAX(CASE WHEN index_column_id = 6 THEN ','+'['+c.name+']' ELSE '' END) +
               MAX(CASE WHEN index_column_id = 7 THEN ','+'['+c.name+']' ELSE '' END) +
               MAX(CASE WHEN index_column_id = 8 THEN ','+'['+c.name+']' ELSE '' END) +
               MAX(CASE WHEN index_column_id = 9 THEN ','+'['+c.name+']' ELSE '' END) +
               MAX(CASE WHEN index_column_id = 10 THEN ','+'['+c.name+']' ELSE '' END)
              ) as pk_columns
       FROM sys.indexes i JOIN
            sys.key_constraints kc
            ON i.name = kc.name AND
               kc.type = 'PK' JOIN
            sys.tables t
            ON i.object_id = t.object_id JOIN
            sys.index_columns ic
            ON i.object_id = ic.object_id AND
           i.index_id = ic.index_id JOIN
            sys.columns c
            ON ic.index_column_id = c.column_id AND
               ic.object_id = c.object_id
       GROUP BY t.name, kc.name
      ) pk
      ON pk.t_name = a.t_name 
ORDER BY a.t_name, rownum
```

Answer (score 2):

Optionally, you can control the general scripting behavior of SSMS like so: [Options for scripting SQL Server database objects](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1503/options-for-scripting-sql-server-database-objects/).

Answer (score 1):

I would create stored procs that read from the INFORMATION_SCHEMA views.
Getting the stored proc text is just:

```
    DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(8000)
    SET @SQL=' '

    select  @SQL = @SQL + ROUTINE_DEFINITION
    from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
    where ROUTINE_TYPE='PROCEDURE'
    AND SPECIFIC_NAME = 'updateComments'

    PRINT @SQL
```

The one to script the table would looks something like:

```
DECLARE @tableName VARCHAR(50)
SET @tableName = 'Location' 

-- Need to know how many columns 
DECLARE @NumColumns int
SELECT @NumColumns = MAX(ORDINAL_POSITION)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = @tableName

DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(8000)
SET @SQL=' '

DECLARE @Results TABLE 
(LineNumber int, 
Line VARCHAR(1000))


INSERT INTO @Results
    SELECT 0 AS ORDINAL_POSITION, 
    'CREATE TABLE '+TABLE_SCHEMA+'.'+@tableName+' (' AS Line
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = @tableName

    UNION ALL

    SELECT ORDINAL_POSITION, 
    '['+COLUMN_NAME+'] '+ DATA_TYPE + 
    CASE WHEN DATA_TYPE = 'varchar' OR DATA_TYPE = 'char' 
    THEN '('+ CAST(CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH AS VARCHAR) +')'
    ELSE '' END +
    CASE WHEN IS_NULLABLE = 'NO' 
    THEN ' NULL '
    ELSE ' NOT NULL' END +
    CASE WHEN ORDINAL_POSITION < @NumColumns 
    THEN ', '
    ELSE ' ' END
    AS LINE
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = @tableName

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 999, ' )'


SELECT Line
FROM @Results
ORDER BY LineNumber


SELECT @SQL = @SQL + Line
FROM @Results
ORDER BY LineNumber

SELECT @SQL
PRINT @SQL
```

This creates the simple table script that you want, but it is not complete - doesn't do numeric precision, primary key, etc.  But this is enough to get you started.

I would just make each one of these into a stored proc that takes the object name as a parameter.